# Untar files less than day old

Tags: linux, shell, unix, tar

So I have been working on a solution which would untar new files, that are coming from another server, to a specific folder.
I have individual pieces of the solution but trying to combine them.
Here's what I have done so far.

```
find . -name 'BkupFPTCONS*' -mtime -1 | xargs tar -xvf
```

This will find the tar files less than 24 hours old and extract them. However I need to extract the files to a specific folder in way that root folder would be omitted. Below command is working fine. But again, i need to use it in conjunction with the above command to automate this process.

```
tar -xf BkupFPTCRPOL*.tar.gz -C ./FPTCRPOL --strip-components=1
```

Would appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
find . -name 'BkupFPTCONS*' -mtime -1 -execdir tar -xf {} -C ./FPTCRPOL --strip-components=1 \;
```

notice the `-execdir`, from the man:

```
-execdir utility [argument ...] ;
         The -execdir primary is identical to the -exec primary with
         the exception that utility will be executed from the directory
         that holds the current file.  The filename substituted for 
         the string ``{}'' is not qualified.
```

if you would like to delete the compressed file after extracting the content you could use the `-delete` option:

```
find . -name 'BkupFPTCONS*' -mtime -1 \
    -execdir tar -xf {} -C ./FPTCRPOL --strip-components=1 \; -delete
```